# What is the meaning of "run" and "planetary embodiment" here?

Tags: meaning

The following passage is from a magazine article on the comic book *Saga of the Swamp Thing: Book One* by Alan Moore.

> Alan Moore, along with artists John Totleben and Steve Bissette, gutted the failing character and rebuilt him as equal parts pagan icon and **planetary embodiment. Moores [sic] run** worked the character from every angle, exploring his role as a monster, his history with the planet and the odd connection he had maintained with Alec Holland, the scientist who had supposedly become Swamp Thing.

Answer (score 3):

> **Planetary Embodiment**
>
> The power to become the embodiment of the planet. Variation of Concept
> Embodiment, Universal Force Embodiment and Planetary Manipulation.
>
> **Also Called**
>
> Planet Embodiment
> Planetary Incarnate
> Planetary Personification
> The Planet
> World Embodiment
>
> **Capabilities**
>
> The user embodies and personifies the planet, which
> allows them limitless control over the world and everything connected
> to it. [powerlisting](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Planetary_Embodiment#:%7E:text=The%20user%20embodies%20and%20personifies,and%20everything%20connected%20to%20it.)

> *A **run** is a consecutive string of issues of a particular comic
> series.* It generally refers to a creator’s tenure on that series, i.e.
> Kelly Sue DeConnick’s run on Captain Marvel, Gail Simone’s run on
> Birds of Prey, Fiona Staples’ run on Archie, etc.  [Jessica Plummer,
> "Trades, Runs, Variants, and More: A Guide to Comics Terminology",
> bookriot.com](https://bookriot.com/guide-comics-terminology/#:%7E:text=Run%3A%20A%20run%20is%20a,%27%20run%20on%20Archie%2C%20etc.)  (2017)

> The fictional character the **Swamp Thing** has appeared in five American
> comic book series to date, including several specials, and has crossed
> over into other DC Comics titles. The series found immense popularity
> upon its 1970s debut and **during the mid-late 1980s under Alan Moore**,
> Stephen Bissette, and John Totleben.   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing_(comic_book))